# Adding an exception for a letter

Tags: java

In my program it searches a text file, in this case a list of every word in a dictionary, and adds a number to the count of vowels if aeiou are found in it. I need to add an exception for counting y, it needs to only be counted if none of the other vowels are found in the word. I am fairly new to the concept and wondering if I was going in the right direction. And help would be loved!

```
package TEST;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        int count= 0;

        FileReader FR = new FileReader("Words.txt");
        BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(FR); 

        String Vowels;
        while((Vowels= BR.readLine()) != null) {

                for (int i = 0; i < Vowels.length(); i++) {
                  char c = Vowels.charAt(i);

                if (c=='a'||c=='e'||c=='i'||c=='o'||c=='u' ) {
                       count++;
                 // if (c=='y') {
                 //    count++;

                           }}}
              System.out.println("Total:"+ count);
                }}
```

Comment: Do you need to count the words that does not contains any of the Vowels?

Comment: @Null All words in this have some form of Vowels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be sure that `y` is not contained in the word, you have to wait that all the letters of the words were read. So you should increment the number of y found  for the current word after the for loop if it is relevant, that is if any `a-e-i-o-u` letters were found.

The variables you will need :

- `int countY` to count the number of y found in the current word.
- `boolean isOtherVoyelsThanYfound` to flag if any `a-e-i-o-u` letters were found in the current word.

These should be reinit to `0` and `false` for each new word to analyse.

Here is the idea :

```
while{
...
  boolean isOtherVoyelsThanYfound = false;
  int countY = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < Vowels.length(); i++) {
    char c = Vowels.charAt(i);

    if (c=='a'||c=='e'||c=='i'||c=='o'||c=='u' ) {
         count++;
         isOtherVoyelsThanYfound = true;
    }
    else if (c == 'y'){
        countY++;
    }
  }

  if (!isOtherVoyelsThanYfound){
    count += countY;
  }
... 
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer as it is more efficient than thyagostall's answer (Joshua's post is actually incorrect)

Comment: @PMARINA Makes this one more efficient over the other?

Comment: @PMARINA  Thank your for noticing it :)

Comment: This is more efficient for two reasons (1) you're adding a very small computation for the if statement and (2) you're adding another variable, which will use a small amount more memory. It's not noticeable when running small inputs, but those 1 millisecond comparisons will add up when scanning a dictionary.

Comment: You might need to set `isOtherVoyelsThanYfound =false;` and `countY=0` whenever `space` occurs. Since the OP is reading line by line not only a single word.

Comment: @PMARINA Ah! thank you very much, after testing both of them it for sure is noticeable! Its an extra if vs two scans.

Comment: @Null  each line contained in the word, so  I don't see why a whitespace in the word could be a problem ?

Comment: @Null, I have saw but I would like to understand :)

Comment: this loop `for (int i = 0; i < Vowels.length(); i++) ` will iterate over the whole line, not just a word

Comment: @Null, your logic has an error in the proposed edit since if the last letter is an `y` letter, the count of `y` is never added. Indeed, as soon as the first `else if` is `true` the next `else if` block is never read.

Comment: @Null, yes and ? Can you give me a concrete scenario to understand the risk ?

Comment: take this input sample :
`aaaa aaya bbby`    what would be the result of  `count` ?

Comment: your code: `count=9`, while the correct result is `count=8`.

Comment: since the `countY` will hold the value 2, instead of 1.

Comment: you need to apply what i mentioned above, in order to get the correct results.

Comment: @Null In the word you have entered `aaaa aaya bbby `, the expected result is `7` since only `aeiou` are counted as at least one of these letters is encountered and that we have 7 `a`. And my code should give 7 too as result.

Comment: what about the `y` in `bbby` ?? doesn't counted ?

Comment: @Null read again this part of the OP question. I think you are missed it :) **I need to add an exception for counting y, it needs to only be counted if none of the other vowels are found in the word**

Comment: the word `bbby` doesn't contain any vowels ,shouldn't we count `y` in this case ?

Comment: You have a word by line. So the word is `aaaa aaya bbby`

Comment: OMG! but these are 3 words !!

Comment: and the OP doesn't mentioned that the line contained only 1 word!

Comment: Not explicitly but when you look at the OP code you may suppose without risk that a word in the dictionary is contained in a distinct line in the file. Anyway, not doing it would be very clumsy.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach:

```
while((Vowels= BR.readLine()) != null) {
    boolean foundVowel = false;    

    for (int i = 0; i < Vowels.length(); i++) {
        char c = Vowels.charAt(i);

        if (c=='a'||c=='e'||c=='i'||c=='o'||c=='u') {
            count++;
            foundVowel = true;
        }
    }

    if (!foundVowel) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Vowels.length(); i++) {
            char c = Vowels.charAt(i);

            if (c=='y'||c=='e'||c=='i'||c=='o'||c=='u') {
                count++;
            }
        }        
    }
}
System.out.println("Total:"+ count);
```

Here you scan all the word and when you don't find any vowel, you scan it again just searching **y**s.

Answer (score -1):

Hey you can use another int to count every "y" and count them.
Then in the end you can check if count != 0 or else overwrite it with your yCount.
So your code should look something like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        int count= 0;
        int yCount = 0;

    FileReader FR = new FileReader("Words.txt");
    BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(FR); 

    String Vowels;
    while((Vowels= BR.readLine()) != null) 
    {

            for (int i = 0; i < Vowels.length(); i++) 
            {
              char c = Vowels.charAt(i);

              if (c=='a'||c=='e'||c=='i'||c=='o'||c=='u')
                   count++;

              if (c=='y') 
                   yCount++;

             }

             if(count == 0)
             count = yCount;

          System.out.println("Total:"+ count);
  }
```

This way you dont have to scan the file twice when count == 0.

Comment: This means that all y's are going to be added to ycount. **The OP _specifically_ states** `for counting y, it needs to only be counted if none of the other vowels are found in the word`